# Prove that the topologies being same is equivalent to convergence with respect to nets being same

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem.

If $\mathcal{T}_1,\mathcal{T}_2$ are two topologies on a set $X$, prove that the following two statements are equivalent:

a) $\mathcal{T}_1=\mathcal{T}_2$

b) If $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a net in $E$ and $x \in X$, then
$$
x_i \rightarrow x \mbox{ with respect to } \mathcal{T}_1 \Leftrightarrow x_i \rightarrow x \mbox{ with respect to } \mathcal{T}_2
$$

I could prove a) $\Rightarrow$  b). How do I prove the other way? Can anyone give useful hints?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose b). To see a), note it suffices to see that the closed sets coincide. Can you prove (using the convergence of nets property) that $E \subset X$ is closed in $T_1$ if and only if it is closed in $T_2$?

Comment: I see now. $E$ closed under $T_1$ is same as all $T_1$ limits of all nets in $E$ lie in $E$ itself. By given, $T_1$-limits are same as $T_2$-limits thus making it closed under $T_2$ as well.

Comment: Exactly. You might also say the same holds in reverse, but then you have it.